# Manage dependencies of multiple projects in a single workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace, cocoapods

I have a workspace set like this:

```
MyAppiOS project
MyAppMacOS project
Pods
   AFNetworking
```

Pods project was added to the initial workspace (MyAppiOS project) with the podfile

```
platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '1.1'
```

and the `pod install` command

Now I woud like MyAppMacOS to also link with AFNetworking.
I have seen example of podfiles with multiple targets, but with a common platform. I could not find an example of podfile that would work with multiple platforms.
I also tried using two podfiles for the two projects, but a `pod install` command creates two workspaces.

What is the best way to use CocoaPods in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
MyAppiOS project with folder
    Pods
       AFNetworking
MyAppMacOS project with folder
    Pods
       AFNetworking
MyAppCommon folder
```

You can still add files from MyAppCommon in the platform specific projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, where you specify the workspace that should be created, and the platform for each target/project combination. You can adjust the project files to point to different folders where each platform's source is located.

```
workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
platform :ios

def import_pods
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end

target :'MyAppiOS' do
    platform :ios
  xcodeproj 'MyAppiOS.xcodeproj'
  import_pods
end

target :'MyAppOSX' do
    platform :osx
  xcodeproj 'MyAppOSX.xcodeproj'
  import_pods
end
```